# Error on \usepackage {geometry} text property

Tags: geometry

The following produces error! The error is solved if no space exists between text= and {5in,8in}. This is really weird! Why is this happening with LaTeX?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,onecolumn,oneside, portrait]{article}

\usepackage[text= {5in,8in},centering]{geometry}

\begin{document}





\section{What Endogenous uncertainty is:}
 yes

\subsection{Type as it is : Stochastic and determ! }
on

\subsubsection{Well there is more than it}
Yes  

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Leave no space between `text=` and `{6in, 10in}`.

Comment: Yes but this is a bug of geometry package?

Answer (score 3):

Answering your question in the comment: no this is *not* a bug in `geometry`. In fact, if you do something similar with other packages, it also doesn't work:

```
\usepackage[pdfborder= {0 0 0}]{hyperref}
```

the error is different:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Invalid value `000'
(hyperref)                for option `pdfborder'.
```

but the cause is the same.

This behaviour is implemented in the LaTeX kernel by design. This is the reason that this:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
```

behaves exactly as:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

**But *what exactly* is happening?** You ask. LaTeX's package and class loader, has a `\@pass@ptions` macro that, at some point, uses a construct like

```
\zap@space#2 \@empty
```

where `\zap@space` is defined as:

```
\def\zap@space#1 #2{%
  #1%
  \ifx#2\@empty\else
    \expandafter\zap@space
  \fi
  #2}
```

which clears spaces from option lists. But it also has some interesting consequences (one of which causes your error with `geometry`). Suppose you have the option list `text= {5in,8in}`.

The first call to `\zap@space` is `\zap@space text= {5in,8in} \@empty`. The first argument is delimited by a space token, so `#1` is `text=`.

The second argument goes by TeX's argument grabbing rules: either a single token or a brace delimited group. In the latter case, which is the the one for our example, TeX removes the enclosing braces, so `#2` is `5in,8in`.

The second call to `\zap@space` is then `\zap@space text=5in,8in \@empty`. Here `#1` is `text=5in,8in` and `#2` is `\@empty`, which causes `\zap@space` to exit with `text=5in,8in`!

If you look closely, now you have two options for `geometry`: `text=5in`, and `8in`. The latter is not a valid option, thus the error:

```
! Package keyval Error: 8in undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

The same happens to the example with `hyperref`, except that there are four iterations of `\zap@space` to remove the spaces between the zeros and the final options list is `pdfborder=000`.

**But how do I fix this?**

Well, the obvious fix is to remove the space, so that the first call to `\zap@space` is `\zap@space text={5in,8in} \@empty`, then `#1` is `text={5in,8in}` and all goes well.

The second, less obvious, but sometimes very useful option, is to load Heiko Oberdiek's `kvoptions-patch` package, whose manual even states:

> LaTeX's system of package/class options has some severe limitations
>   that especially affects the value part if options are used as pair of
>   key and value.
>
> - Spaces are removed, regardless where:
>
> ```
> \documentclass[box=0 0 400 600]{article}
> ```
>
> Now each package will see `box=00400600` as global option.