# How to use equal sign inside class option with pgfopts

Tags: pgfkeys, pgfopts

I've created a custom class with key-value options using `pgfopts`. So far this is working fine. Now I would like to create a key which can take a random string including equal sign and comma.

The below example will illustrate my needs.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.cls}
    \ProvidesClass{\jobname}[2018-11-20 v1.0 SE Test package]
    \RequirePackage{pgfopts}
    \pgfkeys{
        testproj/.cd,
        mystuff/.store in = \myValue,
        mystuff = {} % <-- Set default to empty
    }
    \ProcessPgfOptions{/testproj}
    \LoadClass[\myValue]{article}
    \endinput
\end{filecontents}
% ------------------
\documentclass[mystuff = {hello=SE,test=1}]{\jobname}
%\pgfkeys{/testproj/mystuff = {hello=SE}} % <-- working as aspected
\begin{document}
    myValue: \myValue
\end{document}
```

The key *mystuff* should take any string and should be passed as class option. The problem is that *mystuff* will only take *"hello"* as argument instead of the whole content inside the parenthesis *"hello=SE,test=1"*.

How can I manage to pass a random string as class option including a equal sign and a comma using `pgfopts`?

Comment: This is unrelated to `pgfopts`, but it's a consequence of how the option parser is implemented in LaTeX. The option passes through LaTeX's parser before being passed to `pgfopts`. The `kvoptions-patch` package fixes this. You have to load it before the `\documentclass`. I gave an explanation in the post I linked. The situation is different, but the issue boils down to the same. The problem is not with the `=` inside the braces, but with the space around the first `=` sign.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Your are completely right that the problem is the space. When I remove the space between the equal sign the whole content is passed. This will serve my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested by Mr. Marmot :)

What is happening here is not related to `pgfopts`. Any other key-value parser would struggle with the same problem. The LaTeX kernel, by *design*, strips spaces from options, so that, for instance, `\documentclass[12 pt]{article}` will mean exactly the same as `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` ([explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444351/134574)).

The implemented space-removing method plus TeX's argument grabbing rules transform this:

```
\documentclass[mystuff = {hello=SE,test=1}]{\jobname}
```

into this:

```
\documentclass[mystuff=hello=SE,test=1]{\jobname}
```

which means that the `mystuff` option will receive `hello`, and you'll have a stray `=SE,test=1` in the option list.

If you, however, use:

```
\documentclass[mystuff={hello=SE,test=1}]{\jobname}
```

then the option list is passed correctly, because there was no spaces to remove (again, see the linked post above for a detailed explanation).

LaTeX's argument parser wasn't designed to handle key-value pairs, but simple options which would turn something on or off in the code, so this wasn't a worry at the time.

To fix this there's basically two options:

- Remove the spaces. Beware that if you leave a space there the options will be misunderstood with no error message (except the `Unused global option` warning in the log).
- Load the `kvoptions-patch` package before the `\documentclass` (with `\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}`) or before whatever package you are passing the options to. This package re-implements most of LaTeX's option parser, so most of these problems are eliminated.