# Extend book class with options of multiple values

Tags: programming, l3keys

I am writing a class based on `book.cls`, to which I want to have an option that is a list, so I can do

```
\documentclass[languages={french, english}]{testops}
```

I have define the key using `l3key2e`. But it seems that the option parser of the class doesn't allow to use `=`, if all pass the options to `book`.

If I don't pass the all the options to `book`, them the document process. But I would like to pass the options not defined by `l3keys2e` to the class, so I don't have to re-define the usual options of the `book`class (paper size, fontsize, ....).

Is there any way to do this, and at the same time, passing the other options to `book`class?

**MWE**

```
\begin{filecontents}{testops.cls}
    \ProvidesClass{\jobname}[2018-11-20 v1.0 SE Test package]
    \RequirePackage{pgfopts}
    \RequirePackage{expl3,l3keys2e,xparse}

    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \keys_define:nn { testops }
    { languages .default:n = {english},
      languages .clist_gset:N = \g_testops_languages_clist,
    }

    \cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \__printlanguages:
    {
      \clist_use:Nnnn \g_testops_languages_clist { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ~and~ }
    }

    \NewDocumentCommand { \printlanguages} {} {\__printlanguages:}

    \ProcessKeysOptions { testops } % Parses the option list
    \ExplSyntaxOff

    \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book} %%% <-- THIS LINE RISES THE ERROR
    \LoadClass{book}


    \endinput
\end{filecontents}
% ------------------
\documentclass[languages={french,spanish,englis}]{testops}

\begin{document}
\printlanguages
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it _is_ possible (although currently somewhat limited). See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461011/134574), for instance. I suggest you show us a MWE that demonstrates why the options aren't working.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Thank for the link. I provide now a MEW.

Answer (score 2):

Just answering my own question :-)

I learn that we can use the `.unknown` keyword to process the keys that are not known to the `l3keys` system. Them we can pass these options to the underlying `book` class.

```
\begin{filecontents}{testops.cls}
    \ProvidesClass{testops}[2018-11-20 v1.0 SE Test package]
    \RequirePackage{expl3,l3keys2e,xparse}

    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \keys_define:nn { testops }
    { languages .default:n = {english},
      languages .clist_gset:N = \g_testops_languages_clist,
      unknown .code:n = 
      { \msg_term:n { \l_keys_key_tl\ uknown~option~used }
        \PassOptionsToClass { \CurrentOption } { book }}
      }


    \cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \__printlanguages:
    {
      \clist_use:Nnnn \g_testops_languages_clist { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ~and~ }
    }

    \NewDocumentCommand { \printlanguages} {}
    {\__printlanguages:
    }

    \ProcessKeysOptions { testops } % Parses the option list
    \ExplSyntaxOff


    \LoadClass{book}
    \RequirePackage{geometry}

    \endinput
\end{filecontents}
% ------------------
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,languages={french,spanish,englis}]{testops}

\begin{document}
\printlanguages
\end{document}
```