# l3keys2e: best practices to pass options from class to package

Tags: class-options, l3keys

I moved part of the code in a class to a new package. This package can handle a couple of options defined using `l3keys` and processed with `l3keys2e` (one option being multichoice). My problem is that I want to make these options available to the main class. So, the idea is to set the options in `\documentclass` to be passed to the package.

The only way I figured is to define the same options in the class; basically coping `\keys_define` from the package in the class. This code duplication looks quite unelegant to me.

What is the way to avoid this code duplication?

Comment: Use a `unknown` handler in the class and pass all unknown options to the package with `\PassOptionsToPackage{options}{yourpackage}`. Just like you would do with L2e. And please always add a MWE to help us give more specific advice.

Comment: Basically you have already done it. Looking at your last question, you could do exactly the same: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462835/124577